# apt-get upgrade - packages have been kept back: mysql

Tags: upgrade, apt, mysql

On my ubuntu vps, I've this error, What does it mean? Why were packages kept back? I was advised not to do dist-upgrade. My question is not how to solve this, but why this happened?

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not an error, you should run `apt-get dist-upgrade` because in this case, the upgrade of mysql involve adding or removing some others packages. 
If you are afraid of doing so, you can also try to run `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5` which will trigger the update of this particular package (and i think it will handle the 2 others as dependencies).